# How vector copy data to another vector?

Tags: c++, optimization, stl

Let say I've this:

```
const int MAX_BUFFER = 1024;
std::vector<double> AV(MAX_BUFFER);
std::vector<double> CV{ AV };
```

How is `AV` copied into `CV`?

If I have the same using an array of `double`s (i.e., `double[]`) it takes more (tried with a profiler on MSVC and `/Oi`):

```
for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < MAX_BUFFER; sampleIndex++) {
    C[sampleIndex] = A[sampleIndex];
}
```

How does it copy faster? How can I do the same with C++ array standard?

Comment: What do you mean by how? It depends on the optimization level, which will probably use memcpy in /O3.

Comment: Use `std::memcpy`.

Comment: Do you really need to use "standard arrays"? Why not just use vectors?

Comment: Note that optimisations vary depending on the `value_type` of your vectors. For POD (plain, old data) types, such as `double` and `int`, `std::memcpy` will likely be used to achieve the best performance. For non-POD types (such as `std::string`), `std::memcpy` cannot be used

Comment: Did you know about [std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)? It should choose the fastest method. But I would be interested in what code you tested.

Comment: `std::vector` constructor aswell as `std::copy()` usually have specializations for POD types that use `memcpy()` internally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is hard to answer with absolute certainty, as it depends on your toolchain and your optimisation levels and (to some degree) on fate.

I would perhaps expect a strong compiler to optimise your loop into a `memcpy` that does not require counters and individual value copies. Or perhaps not. Certainly it appears that yours isn't doing that.

I would definitely expect the vector copy to do that (because whoever wrote the `vector` implementation is clever and would have spotted this opportunity).

Ultimately you would have to read the implementation's source code to find out for sure.

**If you want to copy your `double[]` contents as fast as possible, use `std::copy`.**

This *should* perform that optimisation. Certainly it won't be any slower than your loop, and could be faster. If for some reason it isn't, you could also try a direct `memcpy` (though this eliminates type safety ).

---

### Why is `memcpy` faster?

Computers are fast at blatting blocks of bytes in one go, as long as they know up-front that this is what you want to do.

In fact, this is a good lesson in writing code that "says what you mean" and lets the computer decide how to go about it, rather than spelling out the individual steps that you think the task requires and thus making it harder for the computer to do what you *really* meant in the best way possible.

In this context "the computer" is an amorphous partnership of standard library implementation, compiler, and CPU.

Comment: what's the equivalent of `CV{ AV };` once I've created a vector but not init? Such as write `std::vector<double> CV` and lines of code later "block copy" it in the same way? CV = AV? Same "speed"?

Comment: @markzzz Yep, equivalent operation. Slightly faster if you don't need to resize the existing buffer (if any). Because don't forget that first vector construction needed to allocate memory as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve similar brevity and readability with arrays using a standard algorithm:

```
std::copy(A, A + MAX_BUFFER, B);
```

As far speed is concerned, it depends on how the standard library is implemented, and how the compiler optimizes your loop.